# Adding Angular Template Web App To Azure Service Fabric Cluster?

Tags: .net, angular, azure, .net-core, cloud

I have created a .NET Core web API service using service fabric. How can I add an angular front-end to the service fabric cluster. I want to add the web application as a independent service, and do not want to use the .NET Core + Angular template.

One of the steps I have already researched and tried was creating an empty service container and adding a new angular template to it. The cluster doesn't recognize it as a service and it didn't do me any good.

Is anyone familiar with adding a web template as a service with service fabric?

Comment: AFAIK SF projects serve .net or .net core apps and if you don't like to create an angular + .net ( with nothing in .net) then you can try creating a docker image with the angular web app (  nginx to serve the pages) and deploy the docker image as a container service in SF.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, @Aravind!

Comment: I ultimately decoupled the front end application entirely from the back end services. Worked well!

Comment: glad that it worked for you. may be you can post your solution as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0):

For Azure Web App please follow John Papa recommendations:
https://johnpapa.net/deploy-angular-to-azure-vsts-angular-cli/

Another low cost and simple solution is to use Azure Blob for Angular application only. But Blob storage does not support DNS and SSL/HTTPS directly.